# How to modify snippet text of Google Maps v2 Markers in Asynctask?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-asynctask

So, I have searched high and low to find an answer to this problem.

I am trying to figure out how to modify the snippet text of a marker placed on my Google Map (map api v2), in an onPostExecute() call of an asynctask. How I would like to use this in my project, is to update the snippet text once the user has clicked on a marker. Sort of like an update to the information that is pre-set already on that marker.

Example, in order of operation:

1. User selects a marker on my map,
2. Asynctask is triggered (through the onMarkerClickListener())
3. Asynctask preExecute() changes text of snippet to "Fetching next arrival time..."
4. Asynctask doInBackground() queries my database for the requested data
5. Asynctask postExecute() sets the selected marker snippet text to "Next: 4:15PM"

I have tried a few different methods, and have arrived at a concise and reasonable solution, but it does not work. The problem I get, is that the marker needs to be of 'final' type, and when I do that, it does not update the snippet text that is displayed to the user, however it still runs through the asynctask and completes successfully.

The following is the code I've tried:

**map.setOnMarkerClickListener():**

```
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            // Update marker next stop time
            updateMarkerSnippet(marker);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**updateMarkerSnippet():**

```
public void updateMarkerSnippet(final Marker marker) {
    final String title = marker.getTitle();
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> update = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        private String nextArrival = "";

        @Override
        protected Void onPreExecute() {
            marker.setSnippet("Fetching next arrival time...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            nextArrival = db.getNextArrival(title); // db is my database sql class (runs queries)
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            marker.setSnippet("Next: " + nextArrival);
        }
    };
    update.execute((Void[]) null);
}
```

I just don't want the map to hang while my database is sifting through hundreds of time records. Any help is much appreciated, as I'm sure this would help more than just myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known shortcoming in the Android Google Maps API. Take a look [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4645) for some workarounds.

Comment: Thank you for linking me to that issue page. 

[For others]: After thoroughly reading through, I learned that the info panel displayed from the marker is not a live View. Just a pre-rendered image of the contents. I was able to keep all my code just as I have posted above and only needed to add marker.showInfoPanel() in the onPostExecute() method of my async task. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it is intresting because `marker.setPosition` works good but `marker.setSnippet` does not (for my custom snippet layout), I fixed it like this:

```
if(marker.isInfoWindowShown())
{
  marker.hideInfoWindow();
  marker.showInfoWindow();
}
```